# Comment expliquer « soap opera » ?

Tags: anglais, télévision

Linguee [répond](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=soap+opera) essentiellement aux abonnés absents (la première réponse sans correspondance est assez significative), Wikipédia [ne traduit pas](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soap_opera), donne des exemples, et parle à la rigueur de « tout type de feuilleton sentimental », ce qui reste assez flou.

Comment rendre cette notion en français ?

J'ai vaguement songé à « comédie de mœurs », mais je n'en connais pas vraiment davantage le sens, et ça reste d'un emploi des plus rares.

Comment: Petite remarque : la « première réponse » risque de ne pas rester la première réponse bien longtemps.

Comment: La deuxième réponse de Linguee, à savoir _mélodrame_, me parait pas mal ? Il y a encore des exemples de traductions qui me semblent pas mal [là](http://www.babla.fr/anglais-francais/soap-opera). Sinon, moi je ferais comme wikipedia : je ne traduirais pas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Je proposerais **feuilleton à l'eau de rose**, bien qu'on eût pu proposer aussi **mélodrame**, voire même **mélo** qui accentue l'accusation implicite de mièvrerie.

Au Québec, le terme *roman-savon* existe, mais en France cette traduction plus littérale n'a pas pris, en tout cas je ne l'ai jamais entendue.

(Simple remarque, en terme de connotations, une coïncidence amusante à souligner : pour une mauvaise production, on dit parfois *C'est de la soupe!* ... même si les significations des deux termes n'ont rien à voir bien entendu.)

Comment: En passant, des liens avec *roman-fleuve* ? J'aime bien la réponse, je voudrais bien des précisions sur la fin de la première phrase. (Le problème, c'est que pour moi, *mélo*, c'est Mélofée/Mélodelfe, alors…)

Comment: Il me semble que l'usage de la forme abrégée (*un mélo*) a été plus largement employée par les détracteurs du genre, d'où ma remarque sur les connotations, mais ce n'est bien sûr pas une règle absolue.

Comment: ...et on peut en effet considérer le **roman-fleuve** comme un lointain aïeul du *soap opera*, en effet, sur un autre support (roman écrit et non audiovisuel). Au risque de faire hurler certains au crime de lèse-culture, au nom de la comparaison sacrilège de Dallas et des Rougon-Macquart... ;-)

Comment: J'achète, et tant pis si Zola se retourne dans sa tombe.

Answer (score 3):

Bah, *un feuilleton « à la Santa Barbara »*, je ne pense pas qu'on puisse faire plus clair en moins de mots. Tu peux aussi en choisir un autre dans la [liste](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soap_opera#Quotidiens) fournie sur Wikipédia, — *hum… comment dire* — a priori ils se valent tous…

Le savon étant une référence aux sponsors et publicités, « *soap opera* » n'a de sens que par référence aux vielles séries. Donc donner des références me semble bien être la plus fidèle « explication ».

Comment: J'ai hésité à poster ça en commentaire, mais c'est probablement une réponse.

Comment: Pour ceux qui connaissent, ça suffit peut-être, mais un exemple n'en est pas davantage une explication :/

Comment: J'essaye justement d'expliquer qu'il n'y a pas d'explication, parce que la portée du terme est floue.

Comment: Ah c'est drôle ! Puisqu'on parle savon... essaye d'expliquer à un Anglais ce qu'est un bébé cadum, et tu comprendras exactement de quel genre de problème je parle :-)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Gerber baby est une bonne traduction pour un anglophone nord-américain.